# display condition based on post term and status

Tags: php, functions, get-post

im creating display conditions that i will apply to a series of widgets on the single post template - essentially im trying to only get one of the widgets to display if the condition is met.

in this case - the condition is if the current post term is "term a" and the post status is "draft" or "pending".

ill apply this code to each widget but change the term that it relates to.

I cant workout what im doing wrong.

**Current structure**

- post type = "finals"
- taxonomy = "des_num"
- terms = "des_1", "des_2" etc etc

ive tried

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'mytaxonomy' )
$term = array_pop($terms)
```

Full Code below

```
global $post;

$stat = get_post_status($post);

$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post);

$term = array('tax_query' => array(
    array(
    //'field' => 'des-1',
    'terms' => $terms
            )
        )
    );

$cstat = false;
$cterm = false;

if ($stat==='draft'){
$cstat=true;}

elseif ($stat==='pending'){
$cstat=true;}

if ($term==='des-1'){
$cterm=true;}

if($cstat && $cterm){
return true;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating the `$term` variable with a multidimensional array, but type-and-value checking it (`===`) against a string.

Second, you say terms are `'des_1'` and `'des_1'` (with underscore), but are checking for `'des-1'` (with dash).

`wp_get_post_terms` will return an array of term objects, so you should might be better of with [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) for checking if the term is used on the post.

Tip: this might be better readable (and shorter):

```
$cstat = in_array( $stat, ["draft", "pending"] )
$cterm = has_term( 'des_1', 'des_num', $post );
return $cstat && $cterm;
```

or even shorter (but less readable):

```
return in_array( $stat, ["draft", "pending"] ) && has_term( 'des_1', 'des_num', $post );
```

Comment: that was just a typo - problem is, i have to finish with 'return true' because im using a plugin that allows you to put it your own custom php condition on the widget in elementor. and the requirement is it has to return true

Comment: `in_array` and `has_term` both return booleans, so combining them in a return statement with logical AND (`return $cstat && $cterm`) will return a boolean also.

Comment: i tried and, and it still doesnt like me

Comment: turns out - this is the way to do it. 

i adjusted to what you mentioned

```
global $post;

$stat = get_post_status($post);

$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post);

$term = array('tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'terms' => $terms
            )
        )
    );

return in_array( $stat, ["draft", "pending"] ) && has_term( 'final-design-1', 'design_number', $post );